# Locking down write access using a specific UID

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I wanted to make a rule that only I could write to my database when I was logged in.

My understanding is that `".write": "$uid === auth.uid"` only limits writing to authorized users not just specifically to me.

I wasn't 100% sure how to accomplish this so what I ended up doing was setting up a GitHub login (for the 2FA).

I took the UID from that and added it to an admins section of my structure and had the rules check against that.

I'm not sure if that actually works they way I have it setup here so I thought I'd ask the community.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": "root.child('admins').child('uid').val() == auth.uid",
    "admins": {
      ".read": "false"
    },
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": ["id"],
      ".read": "root.child('admins').child('uid').val() == auth.uid"
    },
    "posts": {
      ".indexOn": ["location"],
      ".read": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks correct to me - is there something specific that is making you think otherwise?

Comment: @JeremyW I just don't know the rules that well and wasn't sure if I was doing the correct thing or not. It seems to work the way I want it to but I thought I'd ask people who know more about it than I do.

Comment: Gotcha - better safe than sorry :) Looks like the same kind of thing I've done in the past, and the same rules setup. Looks good to me.

Comment: There's a simulator in the Firebase console that lets you test to see if the rules are working the way you expect.

Answer (score 1):

[Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).

> The Firebase Admin SDK supports defining custom attributes on user
>   accounts. This provides the ability to implement various access
>   control strategies, including role-based access control, in Firebase
>   apps. These custom attributes can give users different levels of
>   access (roles), which are enforced in an application's security rules.
>
> ```
> {
>   "rules": {
>     "adminContent": {
>       ".read": "auth.token.admin === true",
>       ".write": "auth.token.admin === true",
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```